# Is there a Java map that only takes one entry and allows values to be gotten from the map?

Tags: java, dictionary, hash, collections

I want to implement a collection (a bit like a map but for single values rather than pairs) that performs a hash when searching its contents.  I'm trying to make my programs really effcient.  Currently the program uses a HashMap and adds the primary key from a database to it twice:

```
HashMap<Long, Long> userKeys = new HashMap<Long, Long>();
Some operations
userKeys.add(key, key);
```

Is there a Hash or Map I can use to avoid adding the key twice?  As it's a primary key in a database I know there are going to be no duplicates and hence the reason I thought of a hash to be efficient.

I thought a Vector might be a good choice but when I looked at the contains() method it goes through every entry which is going to be very inefficient in this case.

I've also had a look at HashSet's but unfortunately from what I've seen there's no method for extracting values so that they can be used, unlike the HashMaps.get(Object) method.

Desired set up:

```
Collection<Long> userKeys = new Collection<Long>();
Some operations
userKeys.add(key);
```

Desired operations:

`userKeys.contains(key)` <- Uses hash here

`userKeys.get(index)`

Comment: Why would you ever call `get()` if the key and value were the same thing?

Comment: How do you work out the index?  I think you want a `Set` but I'm not sure what the `index` value in your example is.

Comment: You don't need `get()` on a `HashSet` because `contains()` tells you if the set already knows about the object. Or maybe I'm just misunderstanding.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to implement an object pool of user keys, however you need to explain why you are doing this because I suspect it won't do what you want. i.e. `userKeys.get(index)` is likely to be pointless.

Comment: Sorry, I had a feeling it would be a little hard to explain. Essentially my programs does an automated overnight update on a huge set of users (roughly about 6 million) the update ensures that status' in the database for users are in sync with consumer items. And so in my program I go through all these users doing a lot of work. Not sure if I'd need the index here in this case but the use of hashing for checking .contains() would likely improve performs. Would a HashMap for this be really inefficient? I hope this helps explain it a bit better?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think `HashSet` is what you should be using - if you don't *really* have a key/value relationship, it should be all you need. You can get at the values by iterating over the set.

It's not clear what your `get(index)` is meant to return... what's the index here?

If you need to preserve insertion order, you could use `LinkedHashSet`.

If you need to preserve insertion order *and* have random access by insertion order (i.e. get the third entry you added via `get(2)`) then you could keep a `HashSet` and an `ArrayList`, keeping the two in sync yourself. (Encapsulate them in a separate type.) Use the `HashSet` for containment tests, and the `ArrayList` for random access.

Comment: Sorry, I had a feeling it would be a little hard to explain.  Essentially my programs does an automated overnight update on a huge set of users (roughly about 6 million)  the update ensures that status' in the database for users are in sync with consumer items.  And so in my program I go through all these users doing a lot of work.  Not sure if I'd need the index here in this case but the use of hashing for checking .contains() would likely improve performs.  Would a HashMap for this be really inefficient? I hope this helps explain it a bit better?

Comment: @AlexeiBlue: Well nothing you've said so far suggests that `HashSet` isn't the right fit. Just use `for (Long value : set)` to iterate over it.

Comment: Cheers Jon :) Working nicely now.  I was worried about using a Hash Set because I had an array of Objects doing work at the same time however in this cause the array and the iterator should always be of the same size so no worries, I just added an extra check to the while loop to check the size of the array against a current index I was incrementing each time through :)